# Problems Creating a Pure CSS Dropdown Submenu in Submenu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

Hello I was wondering whether this is possible. I have a horizontal menu created using CSS with submenus and it works just fine. However, I want to have submenus appear to the right of the submenus already appearing.

The menu is as such: http://jsfiddle.net/dvpKx/39/

And the code is:

```css
/*First reset ul styles*/
    .nav,
    .nav ul,
    .nav li,
    .nav a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }

/*Now add fixed width & height to the menu along with rounded corners and gradients*/
    .nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: inherit;
    margin: 10px;


    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(198,56,32) 0%, rgb(127,48,35) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(198,56,32,1) 0%, rgb(127,48,35) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(198,56,32) 0%, rgb(127,48,35) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(198,56,32) 0%, rgb(127,48,35) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgb(198,56,32) 0%, rgb(127,48,35) 100%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;


    }


/*Float links left to align links horizontally & position relative to align submenus properly*/

    .nav li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    }


/* 
Styling menu links -
font, color, padding, etc. Then a dark text shadow and a color transition to create a smooth effect when the color changes on hover state. To create the links separator add a border to the left and right and then we will remove the left border from the first link and the right border from the last link. For the hover state we will only change the text color.
 */

    .nav li a {

border-bottom: none;                    

        background: none;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 14px;
        margin: 6px 0;
        line-height: 32px;
        text-decoration: none;

        border-left: 1px solid #393942;
        border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;

        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;

        color: #f3f3f3;
        text-shadow: 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);

        -webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
        transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .nav li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
    .nav li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

    .nav li:hover > a { 
        color: rgb(114,163,45); 
        background: none;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

/* 
SUB MENU 1
We will start to position the sub menu 50px from the top and 0px from the left of the menu item and add bottom rounded corners. We will set the opacity to 0 and on hover state to 1 to create the fade in/out effect. For the slide down/up effect we need to set the list height to 0px when is hidden and to 36px on hover state.
 */

.nav ul {

    position:absolute;

    top: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;

    opacity: 1;
    background: rgb(43,35,34);

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
    transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.nav li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

/* Hiding submenu 1 */
.nav ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
/* When hovered over, show submenu 1 */ 
.nav li:hover > ul li {
    height: 46px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    z-index: 8999;
}
/* Hiding submenu TWO */
.nav ul ul li {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    -ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
    transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
/* When hovered over, show submenu 1 */ 
.nav li:hover > ul ul li {
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0;

    z-index: 9000;
}



/* Setting width of submenu to 100px & add a bottom border instead of left and right ones 
(also removing it from last link)   */

.nav ul li a {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
    margin: 0;


    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #343438;
}

.nav ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
```

​

Comment: I would suggest this plugin: http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#a

Comment: Do you know if there is a way of doing this purely CSS?

Comment: [Check out this](http://www.devinrolsen.com/wp-content/themes/dolsen/demos/css/infinite-sub-menu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the Son of Suckerfish dropdown (a CSS solution).

Code: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/ (specifically the Multi-level dropdown section about 1/2 down). Also, links to examples are shown at the bottom of the page.

Comment: +1 son of suckerfish is a nice kit and is also keyboard navigable (important for accessibility)

Comment: Thank you that is very nice! I also just found another one that was very much what I was looking for here: http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-dropdown-menu and when used in my examples looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bGj3z/

Comment: @user1518633 - Good find. Very similar implementation to the son of suckerfish dropdown, but you're link also prettied it up nicely with some visual effects. Looks great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.menus {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #dcdcdd;
}
.submenus {
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
}
#menu1outer:hover #submenus1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Hope that helps and you can see the sample here:
[reformas integrales madrid](http://www.plusreformas.com)